# Why canvas and other HTML5 tags are not single tags?

Tags: html

I've realized that many tags in HTML5, like **Canvas** and **progress** tags are multi tags

```
<canvas></canvas>

<progress></progress>
```

Couldn't they work just fine like:

```
<canvas/>

<progress/>
```

Are they multi tags just for holding something to display when they don't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the `<canvas>` element it is so you can place content that will be shown to browsers that do not support that element yet:

```
<canvas id="example" width="200" height="200">
This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

For the `<progress>` element it allows you to control the display of the progress text:

```
<section>
 <h2>Task Progress</h2>
 <p>Progress: <progress id="p" max=100><span>0</span>%</progress></p>
 <script>
  var progressBar = document.getElementById('p');
  function updateProgress(newValue) {
    progressBar.value = newValue;
    progressBar.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].textContent = newValue;
  }
 </script>
</section>
```

Comment: This I know, I want to know If it's just because of this

Comment: You can learn more about these elements from the [WHATWG spec page](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/).